# Generate a case when function with an indeterminated number of conditions

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` with a column `x` and I would like to create another column `y` that is determined by some cut points which I would like to provide to a function as an input.

The function should take an indeterminated number of cut points such as in the example below `0, 5, 10, 15`. The function should take another input with the corresponding values for the `y` variable. In the example `3, 6, 9, 12`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(x = 0:20)

mutate(df, y = case_when(x >= 0 & x < 5 ~ 3, 
                         x >= 5 & x < 10 ~ 6,
                         x >= 10 & x < 15 ~ 9, 
                         x >= 15 ~ 12))
```

```
my_cut_points <- c(0, 5, 10, 15)
my_corr_values <- c(3, 6, 9, 12)

my_func <- function(df, cut_points = my_cut_points, corr_values = my_corr_values) {
  ...
}
```

The solution needs to take input vectors of various lengths. However the pattern is always the same. The lower cut point sould be included in the interval and the upper cut point should not be included. It does not need to use `case_when`. It could also use `cut` or whatever provides the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `cut` for this.

```r
my_func <- function(df, cut_points=my_cut_points, corr_values=my_corr_values) {
  
  interv <- cut(df$x, c(cut_points, Inf), right=F, labels=F)
  mutate(df, y=corr_values[interv])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```r
my_func <- function(df, cut_points, corr_values) {
    cut_points[length(cut_points)] <- as.integer(.Machine$integer.max)
    mutate(df, y = case_when(
        length(cut_points) >= 2 &
            x >= cut_points[1] & x < cut_points[2] ~ corr_values[1], 
        length(cut_points) >= 3 &
            x >= cut_points[2] & x < cut_points[3] ~ corr_values[2], 
        length(cut_points) >= 4 &
            x >= cut_points[3] & x < cut_points[4] ~ corr_values[3], 
        length(cut_points) >= 5 &
            x >= cut_points[4] & x < cut_points[5] ~ corr_values[4], 
        length(cut_points) >= 6 &
            x >= cut_points[5] & x < cut_points[6] ~ corr_values[5], 
        length(cut_points) >= 7 &
            x >= cut_points[6] & x < cut_points[7] ~ corr_values[6], 
        length(cut_points) >= 8 &
            x >= cut_points[7] & x < cut_points[8] ~ corr_values[7], 
        length(cut_points) >= 9 &
            x >= cut_points[8] & x < cut_points[9] ~ corr_values[8], 
        length(cut_points) >= 10 &
            x >= cut_points[9] & x < cut_points[10] ~ corr_values[9]))
}
```

Explanation: The above function hard codes a maximum of 10 range checks inside the `case_when()`.  It first assigns the maximum integer value to the *last* entry in the incoming `cut_points` array.  This has the effect of making the last range check in `case_when` essentially behaving like an else.  Also, we check the length of the `cut_points` array before each condition.  For input cuts which are only e.g. of length 3, then only the first two conditions would ever be checked.

Comment: This work for a input vector of length 4. However, what I meant by indeterminated number of conditions is that the input vectors can have different lengths.

Comment: @Roccer Do you know the maximum number of splits you would be expecting here?

Comment: not more than 10.